# What are good cleaners to use on pruning shears?

Tags: cleaning, tools, maintenance, landscaping

I'm new to the realm of shrubbery trimming, though have gotten some good results already.

Now, however, I need to clean my pruning shears so they don't rust / get sticky.

What are good cleansers to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use miracle fluid on mine.  I'm referring to WD-40, of course.  Protects from rust, lubricates, and cleans.

Answer (score 1):

I use Simple Green all purpose cleaner on all our garden tools. Rinse with water, use simple green spray. Rinse again and then towel dry.

Answer (score 0):

WD-40 can rust metal objects, it break down over time and turns into water through oxidation. I rusted out an axe this way.

I use [Rem Oil](http://www.remington.com/products/accessories/gun-care/cleaning-chemicals-and-oils/rem-oil.aspx) with teflon, yes it is primarily a gun lubricant, but what better way to protect your pruners then with something made to work under extreme conditions. I've used it for all my lubrication applications, never has any adverse reactions and the lubrication lasts longer then traditional oil.

Comment: @alli9ndal - while I am also a fan of RemOil, [WD-40](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WD-40) has **never** *caused* rusting in any use I have ever seen in >20 years of using it as a lubricant.

Comment: @warren spray something metal that has a case or similar and leave it for a week DON'T wipe off, just soak.